# I am trying to make a JTable populated with data held in a LinkedList of objects

Tags: java, swing, multidimensional-array, jtable

I have the headings and I wanted to loop through a 2d array so it will hold all of the data.

```
String [] columnNames ={"Name", "Day" , "Month" , "Year"};

Object[][] info = new Object [7][newList.size()-1];

for (int i = 0; i<newList.size(); i++)
{
    info[i][0] = { ""+ newList.get(i).getName() }; 
    info[i][1] = { ""+ newList.get(i).getDay() }; 
}
```

... and so on.

However, this displays the error:

Array constants can only be used in initializers.

How can I fix this?

I later plan to display this in the following way:

```
JTable JTable table = new JTable(info, columnNames);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table),       
  "List",       
  JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE     
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
info[i][0] = { ""+ newList.get(i).getName() };
```

Just omit the { }

The point is: info[i][0] is **not** an array. When using **two** indexes for a two-dim array, you are already "addressing" a **cell** in your table.

So, just go for:

```
info[i][0] = newList.get(i).getName().toString();
```

(assuming that getName() does **not** return a string already; in any case `"" +` is simply not required here, too)

You only use { } when assigning an array in **one shot**, like

```
String strs[] = { "first", "second" };
```

for example!

Comment: Of course! no idea how I didn't catch that. Thanks for the quick answer, really appreciate it